How to specify a dependency to a parent dependency?
I am working on a project:

that depends on multiple Services;
that depends on multiple HttpClient;
that depends on configurations per region: CA, US and EU.

public class CustomersService : ICustomersService
{
    public CustomersService(CustomersHttpClient customersHttpClient)
    // ...
}

public class CustomersHttpClient : ICustomersHttpClient
{
    public CustomersHttpClient(RegionConfiguration configuration)
    // ...
}

public class RegionConfiguration
{
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    // ...
}

I am able to configure the DI:
  
 var caConfiguration = new RegionConfiguration
 {
    BaseUrl = "https://site.ca",
    ApiKey = "secret"
    // ...
 };

 var usConfiguration = new RegionConfiguration
 {
    BaseUrl = "https://site.us",
    ApiKey = "secret"
    // ...
 };

 var euConfiguration = new RegionConfiguration
 {
    BaseUrl = "https://site.eu",
    ApiKey = "secret"
    // ...
 };

 var container = new Container(containerConfiguration =>
            {
                containerConfiguration
                    .For<ICustomerHttpClient>()
                    .Use<CustomerHttpClient>()
                    .Ctor<RegionConfiguration>("configuration")
                    .Is(caConfiguration);
                
                containerConfiguration
                    .For<IInvoiceHttpClient>()
                    .Use<InvoiceHttpClient>()
                    .Ctor<RegionConfiguration>("configuration")
                    .Is(caConfiguration);

                containerConfiguration
                    .For<ICustomersService>()
                    .Use<CustomersService>();

                containerConfiguration
                    .For<IInvoicesService>()
                    .Use<InvoicesService>();
            });

And able to query a region:
            var customersService = container.GetInstance<ICustomersService>();
            var customers = await customersService.GetEnabledCustomersAsync();

            foreach (var customer in customers)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(customer);
            }

But I am not able to specify the RegionConfiguration to the HttpClient to query a specific region.
How should I modify the DI configuration to be able to specify which ConfigurationRegion the HttpClient should use when requesting a service?
Example: one query to retrieve customers from US region and a second  query to retrieve customers from EU region?
GitHub working example: https://github.com/tsawyer999/uri-di/blob/main/UriDi.Console/Program.cs
Thank you very much for your help!

You must named the container configuration by region key (ca,us,eu) first
private static Container CreateContainer(Dictionary<string, RegionConfiguration> configurations)
{
    return new Container(containerConfiguration =>
    {
        foreach (var kvp in configurations) 
        {
            containerConfiguration
                .For<ICustomersService>()
                .Use<CustomersService>()
                .Ctor<ICustomerHttpClient>()
                .Is<CustomerHttpClient>(act =>
                {
                    act.Ctor<RegionConfiguration>("configuration").Is(kvp.Value);
                })
                .Named(kvp.Key);

            containerConfiguration
                .For<IInvoicesService>()
                .Use<InvoicesService>()
                .Ctor<IInvoiceHttpClient>()
                .Is<InvoiceHttpClient>(act =>
                {
                    act.Ctor<RegionConfiguration>("configuration").Is(kvp.Value);
                })
                .Named(kvp.Key);
        }
    });
}

Then:
container.GetInstance<ICustomersService>(region)

